# How to make a simple Totals Chart in SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I am trying to make a bar graph that displays the total units a sales person made and display it in Mobile Report Publisher; EX:

Tim -----

Blake ---

Chad -

Greg --------

My query is simple:

```
SELECT t.Sales_rep, COUNT(t.Sales_rep) as counted
FROM table as t
GROUP BY t.Sales_rep
```

I am having no problem getting data into mobile report publisher.

And this is the result:
[layout of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOUmH.png)

As one can see, none of the numbers are being put in.

If I change the query to:

```
SELECT t.Sales_rep, 1 as counted
FROM table as t
```

And let Mobile Report Publisher do the aggregation, I still get the same result.

If I try to switch Data Structure from By Rows to By Columns I get this:
[with data structure as by columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heKJ2.png)

If I add any other columns, I get the same results posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply using the wrong query? I've created a table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [Sales_rep] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Units]     INT   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

and populated it as follows:

[image: Populated Sales Table]

and then created a data set using the following TSQL:

```
SELECT 
    t.[Sales_rep], 
    SUM(t.[Units]) 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Sales] t 
GROUP BY 
    t.[Sales_rep]
```

I then created a Mobile Report adding a Totals Chart to the main area and setting its data to use the above data set and its properties as follows:

[image: Sales Properties]

Which gives me the following chart output, which I think is what you want:

[image: output]

Hope this helps.

Martin

Comment: Hello Martin, I figured out the issue. For some reason, whenever I had to edit my dataset, Mobile Reports would not reflect the changes. To solve my issue, I needed to delete the dataset, and readd the new one.